# Почему не получается подключиться к User PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio

Пытаюсь создать Телеграмм бота с использованием библиотеки aiogram. Дело дошло до создания базы данных. Изначально хотел использовать SQLite, но нашел информацию, что лучше использовать PostgreSQL, так как у него есть асинхронные коннекторы и одной из лучших библиотек для этого в настоящий момент является asyncpg.
Установил на свой ПК (Windows 10) PostgreSQL и PgAdmin4. Создал Usera и базу для него как указано [тут](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/bazy-dannykh/uchebnik-postgresql/7-sozdat-izmenit-dobavit-udalit-polzovatelia).

Однако при подключении к базе по коду:

```
class PgDatabase:

    def __init__(self, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
        self.pool: asyncpg.pool.Pool = loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncpg.create_pool(
                user=PgUser,
                password=PgPassword,
                host=ip
            )
        )
test_connect = PgDatabase(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

Постоянно возникает ошибка `asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError: password authentication failed for user "TestUser"`.

При входе в PgAdmin данный пользователь есть, пароль к нему указан верно. Из-за чего может возникать ошибка и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Кажется на linux была проблема в config-e. На windows скорее всего тоже, только нужно понять где находится этот файл

Comment: https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=postgresql-users , Для psql это можно посмотреть здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465475/where-is-the-postgresql-config-file-postgresql-conf-on-windows И еще полезная информация для пользователей windows